# how to keep track of status through many steps

Tags: c++, status

I am working on some code that it difficult to re-factor because of its status checking. I am trying to figure out better way to solve this such that I can keep my code clean/readable. Here is a snippet of what the code looks like:

```
int status = FAILED;

status = fn_action_one();

if (status != SUCCESS)
{
    printf("ERROR: returned from fn_action_one()\n");
}
else
{
    status = fn_action_two();
}

if (status != SUCCESS)
{
    printf("ERROR: returned from fn_action_two()\n");
}
else
{
    status = fn_action_three();
}
```

For me the problem is that I now want to refactor this code and loop through parts of it:

```
int status = FAILED;

status = fn_action_one();

if (status != SUCCESS)
{
    printf("ERROR: returned from fn_action_one()\n");
}
else
{
    // This task is now required to be done multiple times...
    for (int i = 0; i < numLoop; i++)
    {
        status = fn_action_two(i); // Keeping track of the status here is now an issue
    }
}

// If any of the looped action_two's had a fail this check should fail
if (status != SUCCESS)
{
    printf("ERROR: returned from fn_action_two()\n");
}
else
{
    status = fn_action_three();
}
```

This now becomes difficult because when looping I want to keep looping through all `numLoop` times (whatever that is) and yet if one fails the status should stay failed.

Is there a clean way to do this? or maybe there is a pattern for this?

**EDIT: enum for status values**

```
enum status_vals
{
    SUCCESS = 0,
    FAILED = -1,
    FAILED_TIMEOUT = -2,
    FAILED_FATAL = -3,
        etc...
}
```

Comment: What are the values of `FAILED` and `SUCCESS`?

Comment: I will add an enum using values from the real code

Answer (score 3):

The 'pattern' is to use exception handling. If you can't modify fn_action_xxx() then write wrappers

```
void my_action_one()
{
    int status = fn_action_one();
    if (status != SUCCESS)
         throw std::runtime_error("ERROR: returned from fn_action_one()");
}

...

try
{
    my_action_one();
    for (int i = 0; i < numLoop; i++)
    {
        my_action_two(i);
    }
    my_action_three();
}
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    printf("%s\n", e.what());
}
```

The brittleness of status checking is one of the motivations for exceptions. By separating the error handling from the main flow of the program you get much clearer code.

Comment: This `might` be too heavy a change for using everywhere in my code-base - even if its the right thing to do :(, but I can use it in places and for new bits of code, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As kinda "C" approach I would use combination of macro and goto.

```
#define CHECK(expr) \
  { \
    if( SUCCESS != (status = expr) ){ \
    printf("ERROR: returned from " #EXPR "\n"); \ 
    goto End
  } \
}


int status = FAILED;

CHECK(fn_action_one());

End:
return status;
```

While within the loop I would do

```
  if (status != SUCCESS)
  {
     status = fn_action_two(i);
  }
```

Comment: Definatley useful, thanks :), but I want to try to stay more c++

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the current code structure as closely as possible, and minimize the changes necessary to implement the required functionality, you'd probably do it by adding a Boolean to track whether any of the invocations in the loop failed, then set `status` based on that:

```
int status = FAILED;

status = fn_action_one();

if (status != SUCCESS)
{
    printf("ERROR: returned from fn_action_one()\n");
}
else
{
    bool failed = false;
    // This task is now required to be done multiple times...
    for (int i = 0; i < numLoop; i++)
       failed |= (fn_action_two(i) == FAILED);
}
if (failed)
    status = FAILED;

// If any of the looped action_two's had a fail this check should fail
if (status != SUCCESS)
{
    printf("ERROR: returned from fn_action_two()\n");
}
else
{
    status = fn_action_three();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is probably the best solution for me to "retro fit" to my code until I can do some kind of full over-haul :o. Thanks :)